# REDIS used memory trending upwards

Tags: memory-leaks, redis, elastic-stack

So I have implemented ELK using REDIS as a caching layer.
I am using REDIS 3.0.4 from an RPM I found for Redhat EL6.
I am also running jemalloc 3.6.0.

I believe the configuration for REDIS is largely vanilla with the exception of a max memory cap and also non-default eviction policy.

```
maxmemory 500mb
```

and

```
maxmemory-policy allkeys-random
```

though I feel that the eviction policy is probably not required.

Now I have verified that the store is generally empty, i.e. my logstash indexer is doing its job well and the data is making it into Elastic Search.
What concerns me is the used memory for REDIS continues to trend upwards and from what I have seen, if used memory hits max, which it has done, then REDIS stop working, i.e. no more log entries flow through.

So, what am I missing:

- Am I being paranoid and can dismiss what I am seeing.
- Should I avoid the pre-packaged RPMs.
- Is there some additional settings I need to change.

Everything I have read to date about REDIS and ELK suggests that out of the box should be fine.

> Be aware that this is a lightweight implementation which I hope will provide impetus for a more broader, bullet proof implementation, which is the reason for the 500MB limit.

Comment: I have since update REDIS to 3.0.5.
Info at 8:22AM AWST stripped down to fit:
# Server
redis_version:3.0.5
redis_git_sha1:00000000
redis_git_dirty:0
redis_build_id:cfc7e460e931db7b
redis_mode:standalone
arch_bits:64
multiplexing_api:epoll
gcc_version:4.4.7
uptime_in_seconds:240680
uptime_in_days:2
hz:10
lru_clock:5138343
config_file:/etc/redis.conf  
  
# Memory
used_memory:152672496
used_memory_human:145.60M
used_memory_rss:157126656
used_memory_peak:152692032
used_memory_peak_human:145.62M
used_memory_lua:36864
mem_fragmentation_ratio:1.03
mem_allocator:jemalloc-3.6.0

Comment: info at 10:23AM AWST # Server
redis_version:3.0.5
redis_git_sha1:00000000
redis_git_dirty:0
redis_build_id:cfc7e460e931db7b
redis_mode:standalone
os:Linux 2.6.32-573.el6.x86_64 x86_64
arch_bits:64
multiplexing_api:epoll
gcc_version:4.4.7
uptime_in_seconds:247911
uptime_in_days:2
hz:10
lru_clock:5145574
config_file:/etc/redis.conf
# Memory
used_memory:154929232
used_memory_human:147.75M
used_memory_rss:159223808
used_memory_peak:154965152
used_memory_peak_human:147.79M
used_memory_lua:36864
mem_fragmentation_ratio:1.03
mem_allocator:jemalloc-3.6.0

Comment: Over the weekend, trend continues# Memory
used_memory:236555072
used_memory_human:225.60M
used_memory_rss:221564928
used_memory_peak:236590992
used_memory_peak_human:225.63M
used_memory_lua:36864
mem_fragmentation_ratio:0.94
mem_allocator:jemalloc-3.6.0

Comment: For whatever reason, perhaps a server restart, REDIS 3.6.0 is running fine with memory usage running consistently low. For a couple of months now.